# Splitting of a short exact sequence in cohomology due to torsion

Tags: algebraic-geometry, hodge-theory

Consider a set $S$ of $n$ torsion points on an elliptic curve $E$, then I find in a paper a claim without any further comment, that the following short exact sequence splits, as a sequence of Mixed Hodge Structures:
$$
0 \rightarrow H^1(E,\mathbb{Q}) \rightarrow H^1(E\setminus S, \mathbb{Q}) \xrightarrow{Residue} (H^0(S,\mathbb{Q})(-1))^{deg \, 0} \rightarrow 0
$$
It would be very much appreciated if anyone has an idea why.

Comment: This is explained in example 3.8 (and the surrounding discussion) in S. Filip: "Splitting mixed Hodge structures over affine invariant manifolds".

Comment: Actually, the extension class of the sequence is the Abel-Jacobi image of the degree zero divisors in $S$.